# Should I have to use WML/HTML?

Tags: mobile, markup, wml

I have to optimize my website to mobile version. So, should I have to strictly use WML only or can I manage with HTML (xHTML with 240 X 320 or something). I never worked with WML/XML and I have enough knowledge in HTML. Will my website encounter any issues when I use HTML instead of WML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465898/wap-wml-still-relevant-in-2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use (X)HTML in combination with CSS to optimize the site to a mobile version since nowadays all widely used mobile devices use these two standards. Also it's easier to convert (X)HTML code to HTML5 in the future.

With CSS you can easely use the same HTML for multiple screen sizes like 480x800 and 240x320.

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility concerns, you may want to use WML but if you prefer to present the end-user with custom pages based on the capabilities it may have, then you may present dynamic contents. Note that not all devices support HTML and CSS capability is very limited.

CHTML is more widely used on mobile than HTML, I suppose.